# PHPUnit: Fatal error: Cannot use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Stub as Stub because the name is already in use

Tags: php, phpunit

I did the PHPUnit installation, as explained on the PHPUnit website.
And at the end, when executing the command:

```
phpunit --version
```

Show me this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Stub as Stub
>   because the name is already in use in
>   phar://C:/bin/phpunit.phar/phpunit-mock-objects/Builder/InvocationMocker.php
>   on line 16

I use last version 6.5.5.
Try other versions and the version 5.0.0 work correctly!

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Please state step by step how you installed, instead of "as explained on the PHPUnit website", to help people see if you missed something.

Comment: This six steps: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.phar.windows
The PHP version is 7.0.0. It's in the Wamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem with phpunit-6.5.6 and php-7.0.0 / php-7.0.27.

I solved it with updating php-7.0.* to php-7.1.14.

Comment: Yes, the solution to the problem is obtained by installing other versions that are compatible with php!